# Why is それ marked with a で particle in "それでいいですよ"?

Tags: nuances, particles, particle-が, particle-で

> それでいいですよ。

I assume this translates to something like "That is good".

But why is それ marked by a で particle here instead of, say, a が or a は particle? It seems that それ is acting as the subject of the sentence, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally tend to think of で as the "context particle".  Another way of thinking of it is that a lot of the time it equates roughly with saying "with/using".  So, with that interpretation, what「それでいい(です)(よ)」is actually saying is:

"In the context of that (それで), it is good (いい)"
or
"with/using that (それで), it is good (いい)"

That is, it is not saying that the thing itself is good (それはいい / それがいい) as much as it is saying that if we look at other things in the context of that, or do things using that, or apply that in some way to the situation, then things (in general) will be good/sufficient/etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very interesting example of the difference usages of が and で.

> それでいい

In this usage, で means something to the effect of "That thing is good enough." "It's okay." "We don't need anything better than that. We will make do with it."

> それがいい

This usage is a typical example of が being exhaustive listing. "THAT thing is good." "THAT is what we want."

So for example if your spouse asks what you want to eat for dinner, you may say 昨日のカレーでいい. "Let's just have yesterday's leftover curry." You could do with other options, but you don't want to bother. Curry is okay. If you say カレーがいい, you mean you really want to eat curry and that is the thing you want.

Comment: And on the topic, 「カレーはいい」 can mean 'No, not curry'

Comment: What is the subject of the sentence "それでいい"? It can't be それ when で is used, correct?

Comment: @George The speaker. You can also say "俺はそれでいいや"

Comment: But you can also say 夕食はそれでいい. Does that mean 夕食 is the subject?

Comment: @aguijonazo I admit I conflated the subject with the topic a bit there, but I think that's what subjects do. Subjects take over the role of topic in a lot of cases, but in other cases don't. Japanese is a topic-prominent language, with a large part of its syntax following the topic-comment structure. A subject, in most cases, is linked to a verb or verbs. 夕食 in 夕食はそれでいい is a topic, not a subject, as it has no predicate to to go with. But I do think 俺 in 俺はそれでいい is different (hedging a bit because of the unique syntactical functions of は) and could be a subject.

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to not rely on the meaning of the statement to find the verb that corresponds to 俺. I cant' seem to do it. I don't know if I can safely say the verb is omitted. I'm stumped here.

Comment: If some verb is omitted, it must be common whether それ is marked with で or が as （俺は）それがいい and （俺は）それでいい both express the speaker’s opinion. It must be something along the lines of 思う. I find it strange to say that the subject is それ in the former but 俺 in the latter.

Comment: IMHO, the subject here is an unspecified "things in general" or "the situation".  It is neither それ nor 俺..  (see my other answer).  There is not any omitted verb here, it's just saying "As far as I'm concerned, things are good with that"/"things are good that way" or "Regarding dinner, things will be good if we have/do that", etc.

Comment: @Foogod I think OP's follow-up question is about syntax, and pretty sure that's the conversation I am having with aguijonazo as well. You seem to be understanding this purely based on the question of "what it means" namely semantics. But "subject" is a concept in syntax. If I wasn't clear in my previous comments, I was trying to avoid having to fall back on the crutch of semantics and see if we could approach this purely syntactically. Semantically there's ofc more than one way to understand this. We shouldn't need to look at the English translations

Comment: @EddieKal Yes, I entirely understand that subject and topic are not the same thing. 
 If you're talking purely syntactically then I'm not sure what the big question is. 
 Syntactically, the obvious answer, IMHO, is that the subject is simply unspecified/implied and not present in the sentence, as is very common with many many sentences in Japanese.

Comment: @Foogod I agree that in a lot of cases the subject seems implied, and that's also the angle from which I made my reply to OP. But if you consider "the situation" as the subject of the sentence, it means 1. "the situation" exists or could exist syntactically. 2. It is linked to a verb (supposedly because that's the popular understanding of the syntactic "subject", unless academic sources that claim otherwise are given). aguijonazo's comments have presented a very interesting issue, I think, which complicated the discussion. I think it is a pretty difficult topic.

Comment: @EddieKal Well, I know some people have differing ideas of what "subject" means when talking about Japanese, but in most contexts I've seen, when talking about a descriptive sentence using an い-adjective, the "subject" is just the thing being described, and it is "linked to" the い-adjective (which functions as a verb for all intents and purposes).  It can either be the same as the topic or different from it, and in the latter case is usually specified with が.  In this particular case, it is different from the topic, but also unspecified.  If specified, it would use が, for example: 俺は状況がそれでいい.